# Problems with onclick / calculating a sum

Tags: javascript, sum

Let me start by saying, that while  I have some programming experiencing (some basic C from a college class and I once wrote a FORTRAN programm in college for a professor), I am utterly new to JS and  beginning to get a bit frustrated.

For some reason, even after reading tutorials and watching several YouTube videos on objects, I seem unable to wrap my head around it. I understand the fundamentals and have no problems doing very basic stuff, like writing a loop that prints out increments on a HTML site, but every time I try something practical, I am completely at a loss.

Here is my current problem: I have created this HTML site that generates a shopping list. Basically, when I click on one of the buttons next to an item name, it adds that item to the list in the middle of my screen. Thanks to Google I found a piece of JavaScript code  which, through try and error,  I managed to tweak for this purpose:

```
<!-- click this button to add the item-->
<button onclick="myFunction('ITEM1', 100)"  class="sidebarbuttons"  >ITEM1 </button>

 /*   Create a List one line at a time- */  
        <script> 
            function myFunction( x, y ) {                       
                var node = document.createElement("LI" );    
                var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
                    node.appendChild(textnode);
                    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
                                        }
        </script>
```

So far, so good. Now I want to get the net price for all the items. Which means, When  I click the button, I want a function to add the price of that item to a variable and then display that variable in a  field with

```
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total_sum;
```

Here's my question: how, oh my god, how do I do this? I thought I could add the following:

```
        function myfunction(x,y){ 

                          var sum = 0;
                          var sum+=y;

                          }
                          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'sum';
```

Obviously, this doesn't work at all. Can you please give me some hints what I have to do to make this work?

Comment: loop through all items in your shopping cart, adding their value to a variable `sum` declared in a block above.

Comment: createnew global variable and sum all value of items add

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

please consider to study JavaScript better, because it's a falsy easy programming language and it's very dangerous to copy&paste without knowing the language. It's quite normal to read a lot, watch a lot and don't know where to start, and it's the main reason because people hates JavaScript: because we don't know well JavaScript. So consider to read the book series "You Don't Know" by Kyle Simpson.

About your question. You can add a variable to storage the sum of your items and when you click to an item, you can add to it:

```
var total_sum = 0;

function myFunction( x, y ) {                       
  var node = document.createElement("LI" );    
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
  showResults(y);
}

function showResults(price){
  total_sum += parseFloat(price)
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = total_sum;
}
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jeteyoj/edit?html,js,output)

Let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

So you are on the right track. Picking up where you left off in your last code block, there are few things you will need to change.

```
//declare the variable outside of the function... otherwise it will only be available to you within that function.
var totalSum = 0; 

// then within your function you will be able to successfully add to the global totalSum variable
function calculateSum(x){
    totalSum += x;

    // and lastly... set the innerHTML within the function... which should equal the variable totalSum
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totalSum;
}
```

Hope this helps.